# Immutable alternative to `delete` in Ruby

Tags: ruby, immutability

Is there a version of `Hash#delete` as below:

```
hash = {a: 1}
hash.delete(:a) # => 1
hash # => {}
```

that returns a hash without `:a`, without mutating the original hash so that it would have its original value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject).

```
hash.reject { |k,_| k == :a }
  #=> {}
hash
  #=> {:a=>1}
```

This of course does not depend on the hash having a single key-value pair.

Comment: Surprised there's not a method for just taking a key

Comment: What do you mean @babonk? similar to what [except](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) does?

Comment: @SebastianPalma, ah a Rails method.